# Reactjs setstate by field

Tags: reactjs

In React js component I have this code

```
this.state.author[field] = value;
```

In the console I got a warning: Do not mutate state directly. Use `setState()`

How could I put author with [] in setState?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/react-set-state-in-for-nested-state

Comment: my question is about a field selector in square brackets []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *field* is a variable that holds the key, you can do this:

```
this.setState({author: {...this.state.author, [field]: value}})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**
```

React uses setState function to update the state of component, you can do somethings like below

**

```
let newAuthor = [...this.state.author];
newAuthor[field] = value;
this.setState({author:newAuthor});
```